# Automatically enable/disable data mobile on galaxy s3

Tags: wi-fi

i going to turn on my data to use internet, but the Wi-Fi symbol going on then off what should i do...
please help me...
my phone: Galaxy S3 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your initial question seems a bit vague, so I'm goign to assume that you're asking why when wifi is turned on, cellular data goes off. If this is not the question you are asking, please ignore my answer.

---

That is how android is designed to handle data. When Wi-fi is on, Mobile Data does not get used.

If you want to keep mobile data active even while wifi is on, go to Settings > developer options > Under networking section you'll find an option  "Cellular data always active". Turn that on. This does not mean that cellular data will be used when wifi is on. It only means that automatic switiching between wifi and cellular data will happen a lot faster.

Comment: Dear Blueren
I followed-up your guidance but there is not any Networking section in my phone. only this sections are availble:
>make but report
>Debugging
>Input
>Drawing
>Hardware-accelerator rendering
>Monitoring
>Apps
could you guide me more please if ...

Comment: Oh No. I guess Samsung has not added those specific options under the developer options. Eitherway, I don't believe this should be any real problem. Why do you want to force enable your cellular data while on wifi? Is there any specific valid reason?

Comment: dear bro: . ... once more i faced up with same problem in another galaxy mobile ... when i changed the SIM, then my mobile worked normally ... and also i checkedup the same SIM in another mobile that was working fine in other mobile the case is that ... the 3G or H+ symbol become hide and unhide – yaseen 7 mins ago

Comment: Dear Blueren
thank you so much bro ,,, i solved the issue by help of related company the problem was from that side ...